# Get the most recent folder using PImage (processing)

Tags: java, image, processing

im trying to figure out how to pick out the most recent folder created to load into PImage. I cant figure out a way.

I have two sketches, one that creates a bunch of images, and one that loads them in. This is the one that loads them in.

A new folder is created within my sketches data folder each time the other sketch runs. I need to pick out the most recent folder created and load it into my PImage. It looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cljL.jpg
So the name of the next folder would be called test_segments2, then test segments3...and so on.

CODE:

```
final int len = 25;
final float thresh = 170;

boolean newDesign = false;
PImage pic;

ArrayList<PImage> imgContainer;
int n = 1;

void setup() {
    size(800, 800, P2D);
    colorMode(RGB, 255);
    background(250, 250, 250);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    // imageMode(CENTER);

    pic = loadImage("hand.jpg");
    pic.resize(width, height);
    color c1 = color(200, 25, 25);
    color c2 = color(25, 255, 200);

    imgContainer = new ArrayList<PImage>();
    PImage pimg1 = loadImage("THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE PATH OF MOST RECENT FOLDER CREATED TO GO");
    pimg1.resize(50, 50);
    noLoop();
    noStroke();
}

void draw() {
    if (newDesign == false) {
        return;
    }

    pic.loadPixels();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 40) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 40) {
            int index = y * width + x;
            color pixelValue = pic.pixels[index];
            color rgb = pixelValue;
            int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF; // Faster way of getting red(argb)
            int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF; // Faster way of getting green(argb)
            int b = rgb & 0xFF;

            // How far is the current color from white
            float dista = dist(r, g, b, 255, 255, 255);

            // 50 is a threshold value allowing close to white being
            // identified as white
            // This value needs to be adjusted based on your actual
            // background color
            // Next block is processed only if the pixel not white
            if (dista > 30) {
                float pixelBrightness = brightness(pixelValue);
                float imgPicked = constrain(pixelBrightness / thresh, 0, n - 1);
                image(imgContainer.get((int) imgPicked), x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

void mouseReleased() {
    newDesign=!newDesign;
    redraw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `File` class from [the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). It has functions that let you, for example, list all of the files within a directory. You could use this to sort them by name, and then get the most recent one. Or you could even use this class to get the metadata about the file and find the most recently modified file.

Comment: Ok cool. Out of all the file types listed, which would work the best? I see filedatasoure, filefilter, filenamefilter...?

Comment: @guyintightpants I would just start with the `File` class.

Comment: Im just not sure how I'd get the most recent file created using the file class, I honestly can't find what I would need...there are so many functions

Comment: @guyintightpants First, find the function that gives you a list of all of the files in a directory. Googling something like "Java list files in directory" would be a great place to start.

Comment: So I got help and my first sketch creates the directory paths: https://pastebin.com/VNU78Cks  Which looks like: http://imgur.com/a/MeQxG  But im not sure how i'd load these into the Pimage of this sketch.

Comment: @guyintightpants You would pass them into the `loadImage()` function. Please get into the habit of trying something and posting a [mcve] in a new question when you get stuck.

Comment: Sorry, will do next time round. If I have a folder called "test_segments" that is being created in my sketch's data folder, how do I call the folder from the load image? All my images are inside the test_segments folder. I tried the full path, but it didnt work.

Comment: @guyintightpants If you have follow-up questions, please post them in their own question post. Don't forget to include a [mcve] that shows just the problem you're having.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357376/loading-in-folder-outside-of-my-sketchs-data-folder-processing